# Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

So I have a controller that is implementing a search for a file in a database. The user can optionally filter their search by two fields, Organization and Category, or can leave those dropdown menus as "All".

I have 3 tables to work with:

(1)

```
       orgs 
---------------------
orgid   |   orgname
```

(2)

```
       cats 
---------------------
orgid   |   orgname
```

(3)

```
                   files
------------------------------------------
fileid  |   orgid   |   catid   | filename
```

and the file name is what they're searching for. To narrow down the results, I'm working with a mirror of the `files` database and deleting rows from it:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AssetSearch (string selectedOrgName, string selectedCatName, string searchVal)
    {
        PortalData PD = new PortalData();

        if (selectedOrgName != "All")
        {

            var selectedOrgId = PD.orgs.FirstOrDefault(o => o.orgname == selectedOrgName); // Get the orgid corresponding to the selected organization
            if (selectedOrgId == null) return Content("Couldn't find row for organization '" + selectedOrgName + "' in the database."); // Return error message if no such oranization name exists

            (from thisfile in PD.orgs where thisfile.orgid != selectedOrgId select thisfile).Delete(); // Delete all rows that don't have an orgid corresponding to the selected organization

        } // if search is filtered by a specific organization

        if (selectedCatName != "All")
        {

            var selectedCatId = PD.cats.FirstOrDefault(c => c.catname == selectedCatName); // Get the catid corresponding to the selected category 
            if (selectedCatId == null) return Content("Couldn't find row for category '" + selectedCatName + "' in the database."); // Return error message if no such organization name exists

            (from thisfile in PD.orgs where thisfile != selectedCatId select thisfile).Delete();

        } // if search is filtered by a specfic category
```

My first question has to do with the error I mentioned in the title. The error is pointing to

```
thisfile.orgid != selectedOrgId
```

and

```
thisfile.orgid != selectedCatId
```

I'm not sure why it doesn't like those expressions, considering that `orgid`s in the SQL database are `int`s and so should be the value returned by `PD.orgs.FirstOrDefault(o => o.orgname == selectedOrgName)`.

My next question is how I can make the messy code above more compact, efficient, readable and reliable.

(I'm a n00b to C#/LINQ/etc., so go easy on me!)

Comment: What are the left and right side data types? I'm guessing you are trying to compare a string value with a numeric one, but the code you posted isn't clear about any data types you are using.

Comment: @Fired: My next question is how I can make the messy code above more compact, efficient, readable and reliable.
This is too broad I think

Comment: "compact, efficient, readable and reliable" The first two are usually directly at odds with the second two. IMO you should aim to make your code reliable first, readable second, and only worry about efficient after you've benchmarked the code to identify specific bottlenecks.

Comment: @JasonWatkins Although unreadable reliable code can easily become unreadable unreliable code (when there are insufficient tests anyway) .. while I *can't* argue with correct/working/reliable code "being the most important", readability/maintainability should be chasing tails with the others significantly further down the spectrum in most cases.

Comment: @user2864740 Which is why you should strive to always have readable and reliable code! But if you have to choose between reliable-but-unreadable and unreliable-but-readable, I'd be hard pressed to make an argument for the latter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var selectedOrgId = PD.orgs.FirstOrDefault(o => o.orgname == selectedOrgName);
```

will be of entity type "Organisation", not it's id,
the same with

```
var selectedCatId = PD.cats.FirstOrDefault(c => c.catname == selectedCatName);
```

So you need to select ID like this:

```
var selectedOrgId = PD.orgs.FirstOrDefault(o => o.orgname == selectedOrgName).OrgID;
```

I'd also suggest you check for null there, that result of the query

```
PD.orgs.FirstOrDefault(o => o.orgname == selectedOrgName)
```

is not null

Answer (score 2):

believe your selectedCatId is still an instance of pd.org   so I think you need to say  thisfile.orgid != selectedCatId.orgid

Answer (score 0):

Two possible changes:

Where you should probably change the name to selectedOrg, not selectedOrgId.

```
 thisfile.orgid != selectedOrg.orgid
```

You could change your query style

```
var orgid = (from o in PD.orgs
            where o.orgname==selectedOrgName
            select o.orgid).FirstOrDefault();
```

As this would give you the id directly and work with your current code.